# Why the controller does not "see" the value entered on the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I've got this on a Rails 3.0.3 view:

```
<%= form_tag line_items_path(:product_id => @product), :remote => true  do %>
  <%= number_field_tag (:amount, 1, { :size => 3, :min => 1}) %>
  <%= submit_tag t('button.add_to_cart'), :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

The view renders quite okay. In the line_items_controller's create method I try to access the number field:

```
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, params[:amount])
```

That did not work, so I tried to examine the number field by printing it to the console:

```
p params[:amount]
```

That printed "nil" no matter what I've entered on the form field. I also printed the whole `params` hash with

```
p params
```

and got

```
{"product_id"=>"1", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items", "locale"=>"fi"}
```

i.e. the `amount` field is not there, which explains the "nil", but I'm a bit (ok, a lot) confused here, as I've read the form_tag documentation, and gathered that the controller should see the field contents via `params[:amount]`, yet it doesn't.

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

/hp

Comment: Form looks good to me. What do you see in the server log?

Comment: Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (82.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 84.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
{"product_id"=>"1", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items", "locale"=>"fi"}
nil


Started POST "/fi/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 28 21:30:19 +0200 2010
  Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"product_id"=>"1", "locale"=>"fi"}
  Cart Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE (`carts`.`id` = 37) LIMIT 1

Comment: That is, there's the "nil" from "p params[:amount] as I described. Other than that, all looks normal.

Comment: What does the HTML that gets rendered look like? Other things to try: use a text_field_tag instead of number_field_tag for testing, and maybe leave out the braces around the size and min parameter (they are actually not needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid right now... The form works now, when it is compeletely inside a `<td>` tag, like this:

```
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
      <%= form_tag line_items_path(:product_id => @product), :remote => true  do  %>
          <%= number_field_tag(:amount, 1, :size => 3, :min => 1) %>
          <%= submit_tag t('button.add_to_cart'), :name => nil %>
      <% end %>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

I had the `form_tag`, and the corresponding `end` before the `<tr>` tag, and after the `</tr>` tag, respectively.

Thank you for your time!